# Normalizar valores separados por virgula para nova tabela

Tags: mysql, normalização

A ideia é deixar de ter a coluna com os valores separados por virgula e passar os mesmos para uma tabela intermédia:

**Tabela origem**

Assumindo uma tabela com o nome `press` com os seguintes campos:

```
id, tag_id
```

Contendo registos tipo:

```
┌───────────┬──────────────┐
│ press_id  │  tag_id      │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│  1        │  1,2,3       │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│  2        │  2,6,5       │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│  3        │  10,450      │
└───────────┴──────────────┘
```

**Tabela Destino**

Pretende-se realizar uma consulta para ler os mesmos e escrever os valores numa nova tabela `press_tags` que vai estabelecer a relação entre a `press` e a `tag`:

```
┌──────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│  id  |  press_id  │  tag_id      │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  1   │  1         │  1           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  2   │  1         │  2           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  3   │  1         │  3           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  4   │  2         │  2           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  5   │  2         │  6           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  6   │  2         │  5           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  7   │  3         │  10          │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  8   │  3         │  450         │
└──────┴────────────┴──────────────┘
```

## Pergunta

Como selecionar todos os registos da tabela de origem e por cada `tag_id` que existe separado por virgula, inserir um registo na tabela destino?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL não tem nenhuma função que nos permita dividir um *string* em múltiplas linhas, pelo que o trabalho torna-se um pouco complexo:

## **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ea9d/1)**

```
INSERT INTO press_tags (press_id, tag_id)
SELECT
    press.press_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(press.tag_id, ',', n.n), ',', -1) tag_id
FROM press
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
    FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a,
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(press.tag_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(press.tag_id, ',', '')))
 ORDER BY press_id, tag_id
```

## Explicação

1. A [sub-consulta](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) com um [pseudônimo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseud%C3%B3nimo) de *n* vai gerar em tempo real uma sequência de números de 1 a 100, neste caso em particular, utilizando `[UNION ALL][4]` e [`CROSS JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).
2. No [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) experior, no [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) interior, vamos obter tudo até ao enésimo elemento em uma lista.

   O [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) exterior vai extrair a porção mais à direta após o último delimitador, conseguindo assim receber a informação do enésimo elemento.
3. `CROSS JOIN` permite-nos produzir um conjunto de linhas que é um produto cartesiano (de 100 linhas em *n*, e todas as linhas da tabela `press`).
4. A condição na cláusula `WHERE` vai filtrar todas as linhas desnecessárias do conjunto de resultados.

Esta consulta vai dividir até 100 `tag_id` por cada registo na tabela de origem. Para o caso em mãos é suficiente, mas se for necessário, pode-se ajustar as sub-consultas.

---

## Cenário comum

Um cenário comum com valores separados por um delimitador numa coluna é a inserção da combinação `valor` + `delimitador`, resultando em algo tipo:

```
valor;valor;valor;
```

Onde a presença do último delimitador, com a solução supra citada, vai gerar um registo em branco na tabela de destino:

```
┌──────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│  id  |  press_id  │  tag_id      │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  1   │  1         │              │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  2   │  1         │  2           │
├──────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│  3   │  1         │  3           │
└──────┴────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Este problema pode ainda refletir-se num erro tipo:

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'tag_id'

Para evitar isto, podemos fazer uso de um outro `SELECT` para selecionar os campos onde a `tag_id` não seja `''` ou `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO press_tags (press_id, tag_id)
SELECT
  result.press_id,
  result.tag_id
FROM (
  # consulta aqui
) AS result
WHERE result.tag_id > ''
```

O que resulta em:

## **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09973/1)**

```
INSERT INTO press_tags (press_id, tag_id)
SELECT
  result.press_id,
  result.tag_id
FROM (
  SELECT
      press.press_id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(press.tag_id, ',', n.n), ',', -1) tag_id
  FROM press
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
      SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
      FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a,
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
      ORDER BY n
  ) n
  WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(press.tag_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(press.tag_id, ',', '')))
  ORDER BY press_id, tag_id
) AS result
WHERE result.tag_id > ''
```

---

<sup>Grande parte desta solução é proveniente das respostas no SOEN nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17269444/352449).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Olha parabéns pela sua resposta @Zuul da p/ ver que tem muita experiência no MySql.

Eu consigo chegar no mesmo resultado, mas de uma maneira mais humilde, talvez até seja considerada uma gambiarra, mas é o que sempre usei como solução para casos deste tipo.

**PREPARAR DADOS**

1. Eu faço um sql que irá gerar um "script":

---

```
select concat('insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select ',press_id,',tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select ', replace(tag_id,',',' union select '),') A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;') 'query' from press;
```

> Esta instrução irá gerar uma saída assim:

```
insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select 1,tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select 1 union select 2 union select 3) A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;
insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select 2,tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select 2 union select 6 union select 5) A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;
insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select 3,tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select 10 union select 450) A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;
```

**EXECUTAR SCRIPT**

2. Pego essa saída e executo como instrução sql:

---

```
mysql> insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select 1,tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select 1 union selec
t 2 union select 3) A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select 2,tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select 2 union selec
t 6 union select 5) A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into press_tags (press_id,tag_id) select 3,tag_id from (select NULL tag_id union select 10 union sele
ct 450) A where tag_id IS NOT NULL;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Como disse é uma forma mais simples, utiliza-se apenas de comandos mais básicos, mas é uma alternativa que funciona ;)

Comment: +1 Esse método revela-se de simples implementação e flexibilidade para inúmeros cenários.