# Como pegar mais de uma categoria do banco na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para assistir filmes online e queria saber como faço para fazer os filmes que estão em 2 categorias serem listados em ambas categorias. Eu estou conseguindo fazer listar somente na primeira... alguém poderia ajudar?

Tenho a tabela de filmes no meu sistema e lá está um campo chamado categoria `varchar(100)`.

codigo:

```
<?php
require "conexao.php";
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria = '$categoria' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 10";
            $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($aux = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
                $nome = $aux['nome'];
                $img = $aux['img'];
                $cate = $aux['categoria'];
                $sinopse = $aux['sinopse'];
                $cod = $aux['id'];
                print"
                        <div class=\"categoria\">
                            <ul class=\"col-md-3\">
                                <li><a id=\"popover\" data-trigger=\"hover\" data-toggle=\"popover\" title=\"$nome\" data-content=\"$sinopse\" href=\"watch.php?cod=$cod\"><img src=\"images/capa/$img\" title=\"$nome\" ></a></li>
                                <span class=\"resto2\">Hdtv</span>
                                <strong class=\"text text-center\">$nome</strong>
                            </ul>
                        </div>";
            }
?>
```

ai esta o codigo eu quero que pegue a categoria e no meu index tenho os href

```
<a href="algumacoisa.php?cat=acao">
```

e tem mais categorias:

```
<a href="algumacoisa.php?cat=aventura">
```

o que eu queria saber e como faco para listar um filme de 2 categorias como no exemplo o filem tem a categoria de acao e aventura.
como faco para ele ser mostrado nas 2 paginas a de acao e a de aventura?

Comment: Já posso adiantar que você precisa rever o mapeamento do seu banco de dados... Coloque o seu código, para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: O campo categoria tem valores separados assim `ação, aventeura, suspense` ? tudo separado por virgula?

Comment: sim eu inseri um separado por virgula nao deu certo depois inseri sem virgula e nao deu certo tambem mas ele esta separado sim

Comment: O Dherik, já tinha cantado a pedra, é melhor vc normalizar essa coluna para não ter problemas, se tiver interesse veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57308/91) ou APENAS em casos temporários veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1792/91)

Comment: Não precisa colocar `resolvido`  basta aceitar a reposta(marcar o sinal verde), veja outro macetes do [site aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa Noite!

E se você tentar utilizar o LIKE do SELECT

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria IS NOT NULL AND categoria like '%$cat%' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 10";
```

"Sou novo aqui, espero aprender mais aqui também"

Comment: obrigado cara funciono perfeito nunca teria pensado em por um filtro ali no sql. se voce puder me explicar o porque do filtro eu agradeco

Comment: Como você tem mais de uma categoria no campo categorias, não se sabe se ele está no meio, no começo ou no fim, por isso do LIKE com % no começo e no fim assim ele procura todos os itens que contem o argumento que você está procurado.

Comment: agora eu intendi valeu mesmo eu achava que sempre que eu tinha um get meu sql teria que ser igual por isso usava p where categoria = $cat para ele passar o valor agora intendi que nem sempre tenho que usar isso que quando tenho 2 valores que precisam ser passados eu posso usar o jeito que voce me explicou valeu mesmo em obrigado

Comment: cara eu nao tinha reparado ontem mas ficou com um erro acabei de reparar eu so tenho um filme listado somente como animacao e este esta aparecendo em acao tambem poderia me ajudar a resolver eu acho que ele esta pegando o acao do animacao por isso esta listando na categoria de acao poderia me ajudar com isso agradeco?

Comment: Nossa, não tinha pensado nisso, mas assim vc pode colocar seus separadores dentro do LIKE (não sei quais são) mas tipo assim '%/$caf/%' para ele pegar só a palavra que está dentro do separador, o LIKE considera espaço se tiver tipo '% $cat %'

Comment: eu to lendo aqui e esta pedindo para eu usar o explode mas estou colocando e nada estou usando ele dentro da variavel $sql ai dps do like eu estava fazedno assim explode('%$cat%'," ") mas nao esta funcionando

Comment: to quase conseguindo cara como que eu pego a letra antes do espaco por que ele esta pegando somente depois com o explode eu coloquei assim meu like '%$cat %'  dai ele esta pegando somente os que tem nome e depois o espaco se eu tirar o espaco do final ele pega todos juntos entao como que eu faco para ele pegar?

Comment: Vc tentou sem explode ?! Porque o explode ele vai gerar um array

Comment: voce fala usar o que vc passo sim tentei mas n mudou nada

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um array com as categorias e fazer um select delas, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria = IN ('acao','aventura')  ORDER BY nome LIMIT 10
```

Como eu não sei como você esta selecionando mais de uma categoria digamos que você altere o seu `href` para algo do tipo:

```
<a href="algumacoisa.php?cat=acao+aventura">
```

Então basta você fazer um `explode` no php para retornar apenas o array que vc deseja `"acao","aventura"` ou pode fazer alguma solução em javascript, por exemplo essa que fiz em `jquery`.

```js
alert($("a").attr('href').slice(20).split("+"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="algumacoisa.php?cat=acao+aventura">Link</a>
```

Já da para ter uma noção.