# Usar explode para separar categorias

Tags: php, mysql

boa tarde como eu poderia usar o explode nesse trecho de código para ele ter mais de uma categoria por filme? agradeço a ajuda

```
$categoria = $_GET['category'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria IS NOT NULL AND categoria LIKE '%$categoria%' ORDER BY nome LIMIT 25";
```

a variavel `$categoria` ela e um get e esta sendo chamada no index no href com ?category=acao
ou se nao for filmes de acao ficaria em outro href ?category=aventura

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o conteúdo da variável `$categoria` pra gente ter uma ideia de como você está recebendo esses dados. Para adicionar mais informações basta clicar em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/83792/edit) logo abaixo da pergunta.

Comment: [Como pegar mais de uma categoria do banco na mesma tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82604/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora o que você está fazendo está sujeito ao SQL Injection, você pode usar o `implode()` para transformar um array para um string.

Supondo que seu $_GET é assim:

```
http://site.com.br/filmes?category=acao&category=romance&category=thriller
```

Você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
$categoria = $_GET['category'];
$likes = implode("%' OR categoria LIKE '%",$categoria);
/* esse implode faz um array assim:
  [0] => 'acao',
  [1] => 'romantico',
  [2] => 'thriller'

  ficar assim:

  "acao%' OR categoria LIKE '%romantico%' OR categoria LIKE '%thriller"
*/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria IS NOT NULL AND ( categoria LIKE '%$likes%' ) ORDER BY nome LIMIT 25";
```

O `explode()` pega um string e se torna em array, por exemplo:

```
$str = "este,e,um,string";
$array = explode(",",$str);
//devovle:
/*
  [0] => "este",
  [1] => "e",
  [2] => "um",
  [3] => "string"
*/
```

Então para usar o `explode()`, o $_GET teria que ser assim:

```
http://site.com.br/filmes?category=acao,romance,thriller
```

E aí a única coisa que muda é:

```
$categoria = explode(',', $_GET['category']);
```

#### Elaboração

Foi esclarecido que seu problema é o fato que `acao` também devolve `animacao` devido a mesmas letras `acao`.

Nesse caso, teria que mudar seu SQL. Tem algumas opções:

1. Use o `IN()`, para igualar certinho. Assim, retorna filmes onde categoria é IGUAL "acao", mas não "animacao" ou "acao-terror".

   `SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria IN ( 'acao' )`
2. Use o `LIKE`, mas com menos `%`. Assim, retorna filmes onde categoria tem "acao" na frente e nao como final de palavra.

   `SELECT * FROM filme WHERE categoria LIKE 'acao%'`

[Aqui está um SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff6be0/1), mostrando um exemplo de ambos os casos.

Comment: Se entendi sua pergunta corretamente, você está querendo pegar um array de categorias e transformar em vários LIKEs de SQL?

Comment: cara a sua resposta esta com o mesmo problema que a dele e a minha ela continua atribuindo animacao em acao por causa do anim-a-c-a-o esse e o erro que quero resolver e nao consigo

Comment: Elaborei um pouco mais - infelizmente na sua pergunta você não mencionou que esse era seu problema.

Comment: não intendi direito onde devo usar o IN em meu código eu usei como você disse where categoria in ('$categoria') ai ele deu erro de sintax

Comment: O erro é `anim-a-c-a-o` ou `anim a c a o`??

Comment: Como assim `anim-a-c-a-o`? Está falando que você passa isso no URL: `?category=anim-a-c-a-o`? Não estou entendendo...

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que o conteúdo de `$_GET['category']` seja por exemplo:

```
$_GET['category'] = "ação, comédia, romance";
```

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
$categorias = !empty($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '';

$categorias = implode("', '", explode(', ', $categorias));

$sql  = "SELECT * 
         FROM filme 
         WHERE 
            categoria IS NOT NULL AND 
            categoria IN ('{$categorias}') 
         ORDER BY nome LIMIT 25";
```

O trecho `$categorias = implode("', '", explode(', ', $categorias));` está fazendo o seguinte:

A parte `explode(', ', $categorias)` explode o conteúdo da variável que é `"ação, comédia, romance"` em um *array* `["ação", "comédia", "romance"]`.
Então a parte `implode("', '", explode(', ', $categorias))` "cola" esse conteúdo que foi "explodido" em uma *string* usando como separador de cada parte a *string* `', '` então o resultado agora é `"ação', 'comédia', 'romance"`.

Com esse resultado podemos usar na condição `IN` do SQL para dizer que o campo tem que ter um valor semelhante a algum dos elementos ou seja `categoria IN ('ação', 'comédia', 'romance')` que quer dizer que o valor do campo `categoria` tem que ser igual a `ação` ou `comédia` ou `romance`.

Ou você pode ainda concatenar vários `LIKE`s, como estava fazendo:

```
$categorias = explode(', ', $categorias);

$sql  = "SELECT * 
         FROM filme 
         WHERE 
            categoria IS NOT NULL AND (";

foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
    $sql .= " categoria LIKE '%{$categoria}%' OR ";
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ' OR ') . ") ORDER BY nome LIMIT 25";
```

Comment: no seu código na primeira parte falto você colocar isso ? entre os 2 get estava dando sintaxe error arrumei mas não foi não ele esta lincando somente o primeiro ainda irei upar 2 fotos para você ver

Comment: aqui estão as 3 imagens tem uma do banco mostrando a categoria esta como ação e animação porem ele não puxa para animação: http://imgur.com/1qzfafh,7CuYOJm,dv1EoMo#0      http://imgur.com/1qzfafh,7CuYOJm,dv1EoMo#1     http://imgur.com/1qzfafh,7CuYOJm,dv1EoMo#2

Comment: junto com o segundo trecho de codigo que voce mostrou ate da certo porem ele esta linkando animacao em acao sem eu mandar ou seja ele esta pegando acao de animacao e atribuindo a acao

Comment: Você está colocando várias categorias em um mesmo campo da tabela? Se for você precisa normalizar seu banco, criar uma tabela só pra relacionar os filmes e categorias (id_filme, id_categoria) @LeonardoCosta

Answer (score 2):

> Sugiro que edite a sua pergunta, pois conforme você mencionou, em uma resposta, o seu problema é outro.

### Minha resposta para o problema:

Utilize essa função, chamada `clean`, para remover os **espaços** ou **traços** entre os caracteres:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '', $string); // Substitui os espaços vazios.
   $string = str_replace('-', '', $string); // Substitui os traços 

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Remove todos os special chars.
}

echo clean('anim a c a o');
echo '<br />';
echo clean('anim-a-c-a-o');
```

### Saída:

```
animacao
animacao
```

[EXEMPLO ONLINE](http://ideone.com/UvggWa)