# Ajuda com a lógica da programação

Tags: php

Tenho uma div que é composta de alguns campos de texto, e um botão que chama uma função js que duplica essa div caso o usuário clique...

**Exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
<div id="duplicar">

<!--.....aqui vai o html dos campos(nao coloquei pq está muito grande)-->     

</div>

<div id="aqui"></div>

<!--botao que chama a função para duplicar a div-->
<div style="width:910px; float:left; margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mais()"; class="btn btn-outlined btn-success"/>         
</div>

<script>
function mais() {
    var destino = document.getElementById("aqui");
    var novadiv = document.createElement("div");
    var conteudo = document.getElementById("duplicar");
    novadiv.innerHTML = conteudo.innerHTML;
    destino.appendChild(novadiv);
}
</script>
```

OK, agora o que eu preciso:

Quando eu dou um submit em meu form, os valores dos campos são passados via POST em forma de array:

item[]
qtd[]
valorunit[]

Pois assim caso o usuario duplique a div 3x por exemplo, o array comporta os 3 valores inseridos...

---

Agora como eu faço para salvar esse array no banco de dados?

-Eu pensei em juntar tudo em uma string, separando por ; (ponto e virgula)...e salvar em uma coluna do banco, isso eu consegui fazer utilizando:

```
//conta o tamanho do array passado via POST
$tam = sizeof($peca);

$grupopeca;

for($c=0; $c < $tam; $c++){
    $grupopeca .= $peca[$c].';'. $qtd[$c].';'.$valorunitario[$c].';';
    #echo $grupopeca;               
}
```

Agora, como eu faço para separar esses dados quando eu for dar um select no banco?

(exemplo caso o array seja de tamanho = 3)
A string vai estar assim:

> Arruela;10;5;Porca;10;6;Parafuso;10;7

Preciso separar da seguinte forma em 3 variaveis:

$item
$qtd
$valorunit

**Item:** Arruela
**Qtd:** 10
**Valor Unit:** 5

**Item:** Porca
**Qtd:** 10
**Valor Unit:** 6

**Item:** Paraduso
**Qtd:** 10
**Valor Unit:** 7

Se houver alguma outra lógica melhor para fazer isso, aceito sugestões.

Comment: Olha os problemas que você pode ter com uma coluna multivalorada, [1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82608/91) e [2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83792/91). O ideal seria: [Normalizar valores separados por virgula para nova tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57308/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charles.

Existe uma razão real para que você guarde tudo em uma coluna no banco separando tudo por ponto e vírgula? Essa é uma má prática principalmente pensando na normalização do banco e na manutenção dessa sua aplicação a longo prazo.

O ideal era você remodelar suas entidades relacionais do banco de dados, deixando assim (por exemplo):

**Tabela de itens dos pedidos**

```
+----+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
| ID |   Item   |  Qtd  | Valor Unit | Id Pedido |
+----+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 1  |  Arruela |  5    |    1.3     |     1     |
+----+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 2  |  Porca   |  3    |    0.3     |     1     |
+----+----------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

**Tabela de pedidos**

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+
| ID |        Data      |  Número Pedido  |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 23/09/2015 08:00 |      0001245    |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
```

E isso te facilitaria muito a vida para manter a sua aplicação, fazer consultas e agregar os dados.

Para fazer o split da string diretamente na SQL como vocÊ quer, vai depender muito do banco de dados que você usa, muitos não vão dar suporte para isso. Então você teria que fazer isso diretamente no PHP.

**MAS** caso você queria apenas pegar essa string e gerar os objetos, pode fazer assim. Novamente não recomendo essa lógica a melhor seria como eu falei criar 2 tabelas relacionadas.

```
$itensConcatenados  = //aqui seu select que traz a coluna concatenada com ; do seu BD

$itensSeparados = explode(";", $itensConcatenados);

$itens = array();

$indexArray = 0;

while ($indexArray < count($itensSeparados)) { 

    //aqui itera pegando e criando um objeto item a cada 3 posiçõpes do array
    //para isso as informações devem estar sempre na mesma ordem
    $item = new item();
    $item->item = $itensSeparados[$indexArray]->item;
    $item->qtd = $itensSeparados[$indexArray++]->qtd;
    $item->valorunit = $itensSeparados[$indexArray++]->valorunit;

    $itens[] = $item;
}

var_dump($itens);


class item
{
    public $item;
    public $qtd;
    public $valorunit;
}
```

Comment: Realmente, usando tabelas relacionadas eu terei um melhor controle sob os valores o que me ajudará futuramente com a manutenção do código. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

ha vários modos de você realizar este processo.

#### BANCO (Ideal)

Criar colunas separadas no banco de dados

```
CREATE TABLE peca{
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('peca_id_seq'::regclass),
    item VARCHAR(255),
    quantidade NUMERIC(12,2),
    valor numeric(12,2)
    CONSTRAINT pk_peca_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
}
```

Na consulta via banco, buscar pelos dados do registro especifico.
Assim ainda possibilitando a pesquisa.

#### JSON

Você pode converter seu `array` para um `JSON` salvar no banco e apos a reversão já traria em formato de `array` novamente.

```
$arrayDados = array();
foreach($peca as $k => $value){
    $arrayDados[$k]['pesa'] = $value;
    $arrayDados[$k]['quantidade'] = $qtd[$k];
    $arrayDados[$k]['pesa'] = $valorunitario[$k];
}
```

No banco salvar com `json_encode($arrayDados)`.
Na hora de recuperar os dados você simplesmente recupera a `string` gerada e desconverte através `json_decode($str, true)`, assim voltando a trabalhar com o `arrayDados`.

#### REGEX

Caso não queira usar nenhuma das duas técnicas acima, apenas pegar o que você já tem e desconverter.

Poderia se usar [REGEX.](https://regex101.com/r/kB2uA0/1)

```
preg_match_all('~([^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+)~', $str, $match);

$arrayDados = array();
foreach($match[1] as $k => $dados){

    $dados = explode(';', $dados);

    $arrayDados[$k]['pesa'] = $dados[0];
    $arrayDados[$k]['quantidade'] = $dados[1];
    $arrayDados[$k]['pesa'] = $dados[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu for coloque o insert na tabela

```
$tam = sizeof($peca); 
$grupopeca = "";
for ($c=0;$c<$tam;$c++){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tabela (item, qtde, valor)
                           values ('$peca[$c]',$qtd[$c],$valorunitario[$c])";
    // aqui codigo (PDO/mysql_query)
}
```

Desta forma será inserido no BD todos os registros capturados do form. É um exemplo, você deve adaptá-lo a sua necessidade.

Comment: Dessa forma não me serve, pois eu pretendo salvar uma STRING dentro do campo GRUPOPECAS do banco. A coluna será varchar.......e o usuario pode incluir infinutas peças

Comment: Veja eu te dei o caminho. O insert você pode fazer da forma que quiser. Uma coluna, várias. Se manter a mesma concatenação, o mesmo exemplo serve. Precisa ter uma chave para fazer as devidas amarrações. Mas o ideal é que a tabela seja normalizada como alguns outros colegas sugeriram.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma é criar uma tabela para adicionar as peças de cada pedido, e obtê-las com um JOIN ao chamar o pedido. Porém, para ficar dentro do escopo do seu problema, mantendo tudo numa só coluna, existem duas maneiras facilitadas no PHP:

Primeiramente, coloque as peças num array associativo:

```
$tam = sizeof($peca);

$grupopeca = [];

for($c = 0; $c < $tam; $c++) {
    $grupopeca[] = [
        'peca' => $peca[$c],
        'qtd' => $qtd[$c],
        'valor' => $valorunitario[$c]
    ];
}
```

Para transformar esse array em uma string, você pode serializar ela:

```
$resultado = serialize($grupopeca);
```

Ou transformá-la numa string JSON (um objeto JSON na verdade, porém serializado em string):

```
$resultado = json_encode($grupopeca);
```

Para reverter ao obter a string do banco:

```
// Reverter o objeto serializado:
$pecas = unserialize($resultado);

// Reverter o JSON:
$pecas = json_decode($resultado, true);
```

Se for seguir essa lógica de manter tudo numa coluna em string, recomendo o caminho do JSON, que é universalmente reconhecido por quase todas as linguagens de programação, frameworks e bancos de dados, além de principalmente poder ser interpretado diretamente pelo Javascript ([JSON = Javascript Object Notation](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)).

Comment: A opção de utilizar array multidimensional é uma boa, fiz uns testes dessa forma e deu certo. Obrigado por me dar essa clareada em minha mente. No entanto resolvi fazer com tabelas no banoc mesmo, pois vai ficar mais fácil para eu dar manutenção futuramente.