# Como fazer consulta com where e like entre duas tabelas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Galera estou com o seguinte problema:

Eu tenho duas tabelas,as seguintes tabelas :

```
tabela mensagens
+----+-------------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | mensagem          | _de   | hora                |
+----+-------------------+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | teste de mensagem | tiago | 2015-12-04 14:56:41 |
+----+-------------------+-------+---------------------+
tabela amigos
+----+--------+--------------+
| id | user   | amigos       |
+----+--------+--------------+
| 1  | italos | igors;tiago; |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

Eu gostaria de fazer a seguinte consulta: que eu recebesse o resultado de todas as mensagens somente se existir na tabela amigos, o valor de _de da tabela mensagens. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: O que você tem até agora. Sauce, plz! Post seu código.

Comment: Relacionado: [Normalizar valores separados por virgula para nova tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57308/91) e [Problemas com campos multivalorados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83792/91)

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de uma tabela para vinculo, fazer pesquisa com varchar ainda mais com multiplos valores, pode tornar sua query pesada e lenta a toa.

```
tabela mensagens
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | mensagem          | hora                |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| 9  | teste de mensagem | 2015-12-04 14:56:41 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+

tabela amigos
+----+--------+
| id | user   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | italos | 
+----+--------+

tabela amigosItem
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
| id | user   | msg    |  amigos      |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
| 5  | 1      | 9      | igors        |
+----+--------+-----------------------+
| 6  | 1      | 9      | tiago        |
+----+--------+-----------------------+

Select A.mensagem 
from amigos A
 Inner join amigosItem AI On A.id = AI.user
 Inner join mensagens M On M.id = AI.msg
```

Ficaria assim.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá Wesley, primeiramente o campo '**amigos**' da **tabela amigos** deverá ser uma nova tabela no banco de dados (**amigo_item**), não é aconselhável você ter um atributo multivalorado em uma tabela.
Uma solução para fazer o select da forma que você quer, é utilizar o **INNER JOIN**. Porém o mesmo só irá funcionar caso o seu banco esteja com todos os relacionamentos corretamente. Tem como gerar um script da estrutura do DB e enviar aqui?