# Remover um determinado valor de varias linhas em uma tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou com dificuldades para criar um algoritmo para fazer varredura e que exclua determinados emails de grupos de emails.

Tenho uma tabela onde são cadastrados e-mails da empresa que são exibidos na intranet, com estes valores são criado grupos de e-mails que são armazenados em outra tabela, o que estou precisando fazer é o seguinte:

-Quando eu excluir um e-mail da tabela de e-mails, que também realize uma busca pelos grupos de e-mails que na coluna fica desta forma `(exemplo1@dominio.local;exemplo2@dominio.local;exemplo3@dominio.local;exemplo4@dominio.local)` e remova dos grupos também, estou tentando fazer desta forma:

```
$email_i =  $_POST["email-interno"];    
$buscagrupos    =   mysql_query("SELECT emails FROM grupoemail WHERE emails LIKE '%$email_i%'");
        while($lc1  =   mysql_fetch_array($buscagrupos)){
            $g_emails       =   $lc1["emails"];
            $g_emailsE  =   explode(";", $g_emails);
            $key = array_search($email_i, $g_emailsE);
            if($key!==false){
            unset($g_emailsE[$key]);
            $g_emails2  =   implode(";", $g_emailsE);
            $teste2 =   mysql_query("UPDATE grupoemail SET email='$g_emails2' WHERE emails LIKE '%$email_i%'");
            }}
```

Mas quando executo isso, o script ta misturando tudo os e-mails e adicionando todos os e-mails existentes das linhas que tinha o e-mail excluído e adicionado todos eles igualmente nas mesmas linhas, então em vez de ocorrer isso:

```
Grupo 1:
exemplo1@dominio.local;exemplo2@dominio.local;exemplo3@dominio.local
Grupo2
exemplo3@dominio.local;exemplo7@dominio.local;exemplo9@dominio.local
```

Exclui o exemplo3 dos emails, estes grupos deveriam ficar sem ele desta forma:

```
Grupo 1:
exemplo1@dominio.local;exemplo2@dominio.local;
Grupo2
exemplo7@dominio.local;exemplo9@dominio.local
```

Mas não, esta ocorrendo isso:

```
Grupo 1:
exemplo1@dominio.local;exemplo2@dominio.local;exemplo3@dominio.local
Grupo2
exemplo3@dominio.local;exemplo7@dominio.local;exemplo9@dominio.local
```

Exclui o exemplo3 dos emails, estes grupos ficam assim:

```
Grupo 1:   exemplo1@dominio.local;exemplo2@dominio.local;exemplo3@dominio.local;exemplo7@dominio.local;exemplo9@dominio.local
Grupo 2: exemplo1@dominio.local;exemplo2@dominio.local;exemplo3@dominio.local;exemplo7@dominio.local;exemplo9@dominio.local
```

Eu sei que meu script esta mal, só não sei como ajustar =(

Comment: Esse coluna é multivalorada?

Comment: Nao, é uma coluna TEXT mesmo.
Gravo os dados nesta forma pois fica fácil depois utilizar somente usando echo 'mailto:'.$emails;

Comment: Tem mais de um email nessa coluna?

Comment: sim, os emaisl fica como dice no exemplo dentro da coluna...
example1@dominio.local;example2@dominio.local;example3@dominio.local;...etc

Comment: Já tentou da um `REPLACE` no update? - `UPDATE grupoemail SET email = REPLACE(REPLACE(email, '$email_i', ''), ';;', ';') WHERE emails LIKE '%$email_i%'"`

Comment: Se puder alterar as tabelas e não for trabalhoso, pode fazer assim => [Normalizar valores separados por virgula para nova tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57308/91)

Comment: Eu não conhecia a função REPLACE na query, vou tentar desta forma, creio que vai dar certo =)

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar usando a função REPLACE, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado a todos que me ajudaram.