# Selecionar somente itens que contem o numero em seu valor

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho uma tabela `conversas`:

**ESTRUTURA**

```
+--------+---------+
|  Nome  |  Tipo   |
+--------+---------+
| id     | int     |
| users  | text    |
| titulo | varchar |
+--------+---------+
```

Preciso que selecionar os itens que contenham o id do usuário logado no campo `users`. 
Exemplo:

tabela conversas:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id |  users  |   titulo   |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | 2;4;3;6 | Conversa 1 |
|  2 | 3;6;12  | Conversa 2 |
|  3 | 1;5;3;7 | Conversa 3 |
|  4 | 8;2;    | Conversa 4 |
|  5 | 1;12;3  | Conversa 5 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Id do usuário: 12

Deve retornar:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | users  |   titulo   |
+----+--------+------------+
|  2 | 3;6;12 | Conversa 2 |
|  5 | 1;12;3 | Conversa 5 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Tentei utilizar:

```
SELECT * FROM `conversas` WHERE users IN (12)
```

e não funcionou muito bem. Como devo fazer?

**-EDIT**

Eu também possuo uma tabela `users` e `mensagens`.

`users`

```
+--------+---------+
|  Nome  |  Tipo   |
+--------+---------+
| id     | int     |
| nome   | varchar |
+--------+---------+
```

`mensagens`

```
+-------------+----------+
|    Nome     |   Tipo   |
+-------------+----------+
| id          | int      |
| id_user     | int      |
| id_conversa | int      |
| mensagem    | text     |
+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Que tal normalizar? Seria bem mais prático trazer os resultados que precisa. Do jeito atual uma alternativa arriscada e que exigiria muita atenção seria usando 'LIKE'

Comment: Como assim "normalizar"?

Comment: Pode ajudar => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1792/91

Comment: [Normalizar valores separados por virgula para nova tabela](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57308/91)

Comment: O código `SELECT * FROM conversas WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12',users);` funciona mas se eu coloco `SELECT * FROM conversas WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12,7',users);` Ele não funciona

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_conversas WHERE users LIKE '%12%';
```

Lembrando que seria mais ideal criar uma tabela de relacionamento à parte pra esse caso.

Comment: eu tenho uma tabela `users` que possui um campo `id`

Comment: Assim não funciona. Se vc tiver um registro com (85;112;30) ele trará o resultado.